# Timeout expired while peer chaincode instantiate

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I use CA to create a multi-node fabric network.

My code is this:https://github.com/fnpac/fabric-web/blob/master/fabric-ca/scripts/run-fabric.sh

Peer config:https://github.com/fnpac/fabric-web/blob/ce7929e59b0ba1bc3a55d16ea66fa08131c294dc/fabric-ca/makeDocker.sh#L207-L272

When I instantiate chaincode, it will report the following error：

```
##### 2018-05-22 09:14:49 Instantiating chaincode on peer1-org2 ...
2018-05-22 09:14:49.374 UTC [msp] GetLocalMSP -> DEBU 001 Returning existing local MSP
2018-05-22 09:14:49.375 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> DEBU 002 Obtaining default signing identity
2018-05-22 09:14:49.382 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 003 Using default escc
2018-05-22 09:14:49.382 UTC [chaincodeCmd] checkChaincodeCmdParams -> INFO 004 Using default vscc
2018-05-22 09:14:49.383 UTC [chaincodeCmd] getChaincodeSpec -> DEBU 005 java chaincode disabled
2018-05-22 09:14:49.383 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 006 Sign: plaintext: 0AAB090A6708031A0C0889BF8FD80510...324D53500A04657363630A0476736363 
2018-05-22 09:14:49.383 UTC [msp/identity] Sign -> DEBU 007 Sign: digest: 754973C8F271A44D0933CD73D9219A51DA5FDD2E84938E6EA10F9DA3E2981692 
Error: Error endorsing chaincode: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = timeout expired while starting chaincode mycc:1.0(networkid:dev,peerid:peer1-org2,tx:a93b69c5243e04171ca16188e733d03671d93bb606819b101125642410d0c911)
Usage:
  peer chaincode instantiate [flags]

Flags:
  -C, --channelID string            The channel on which this command should be executed
```

And the Orderer's log :

```
2018-05-22 09:19:49.391 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 5e1 Kill container dev-peer1-org2-mycc-1.0 (API error (409): {"message":"Cannot kill container: dev-peer1-org2-mycc-1.0: Container 9751bded21b329c2b516386d78fd7a751833fccdde5104a96dcf3f22304ff0d8 is not running"}
)
2018-05-22 09:19:49.400 UTC [dockercontroller] stopInternal -> DEBU 5e2 Removed container dev-peer1-org2-mycc-1.0
2018-05-22 09:19:49.400 UTC [container] unlockContainer -> DEBU 5e3 container lock deleted(dev-peer1-org2-mycc-1.0)
2018-05-22 09:19:49.400 UTC [chaincode] func1 -> DEBU 5e4 chaincode mycc:1.0 launch seq completed
2018-05-22 09:19:49.400 UTC [chaincode] Launch -> ERRO 5e5 launchAndWaitForRegister failed: timeout expired while starting chaincode mycc:1.0(networkid:dev,peerid:peer1-org2,tx:a93b69c5243e04171ca16188e733d03671d93bb606819b101125642410d0c911)
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).launchAndWaitForRegister
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:569
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Launch
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:731
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/exectransaction.go:45
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*SupportImpl).Execute
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/support.go:83
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).callChaincode
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:164
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).simulateProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:265
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser.(*Endorser).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/endorser/endorser.go:491
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*expirationCheckFilter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/expiration.go:61
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter.(*filter).ProcessProposal
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/handlers/auth/filter/filter.go:31
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer._Endorser_ProcessProposal_Handler
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/protos/peer/peer.pb.go:112
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:781
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:981
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/google.golang.org/grpc/server.go:551
runtime.goexit
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:2337
2018-05-22 09:19:49.400 UTC [endorser] callChaincode -> DEBU 5e6 [mychannel][a93b69c5] Exit
2018-05-22 09:19:49.400 UTC [endorser] simulateProposal -> ERRO 5e7 [mychannel][a93b69c5] failed to invoke chaincode name:"lscc" , error: timeout expired while starting chaincode mycc:1.0(networkid:dev,peerid:peer1-org2,tx:a93b69c5243e04171ca16188e733d03671d93bb606819b101125642410d0c911)
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).launchAndWaitForRegister
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:569
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode.(*ChaincodeSupport).Launch
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/chaincode_support.go:731
```

how can i resolve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had fix it.

This is because I execute the `peer chaincode instantiate` operation on another machine and I should execute it on the specified node's machine.

E.g:

```
 # Instantiate the chain code on the first peer node of the first peer organization
 makePolicy
 initPeerVars ${PORGS[0]} 1
 switchToAdminIdentity
 Logr "Instantiating chaincode on $PEER_HOST ..."
 Peer chaincode instantiate -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n mycc -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a","100","b","200"]}' -P "$POLICY" $ORDERER_CONN_ARGS
```

The above script should be executed on the machine of the first peer node of the first peer organization. If you execute the script on other machines, it will be Timeout